# increase paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command() width

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I'm using paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command() to run commands on remote servers.
Does someone know if it's possible to change the width, like with invoke_shell(width=150) ?

When I `exec_command("ls -la")` I get :

```
drwx------.  6 myuser myuser  4096 25 avril 15:59 
.
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root    root     4096  5 mai 15:05 
..
-rw-------.  1 myuser myuser  2818 28 avril 11:09 
.bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 myuser myuser   340 14 avril 14:16 
.bashrc
```

and I want :

```
drwx------.  6 myuser myuser  4096 25 avril 15:59 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root    root     4096  5 mai 15:05 ..
-rw-------.  1 myuser myuser  2818 28 avril 11:09 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--.  1 myuser myuser   340 14 avril 14:16 .bashrc
```

(using exec_command, not invoke_shell)

My code :

```
ssh_client    = paramiko.SSHClient()
mykey         = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/path/to/my/key", password="passphrase")
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect("myserver.mydomain.com", username="myuser", pkey=mykey)
transport     = ssh_client.get_transport()
agent_channel = transport.open_session()
agent_handler = paramiko.agent.AgentRequestHandler(agent_channel)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("ls -la")
```

Comment: I believe this could be accomplished via configuration on the remote server. Does that work for you? What OS are you running?

Comment: Well, from my linux shell if I execute `ssh myuser@myserver.mydomain.com "ls -la"` I get what I want the lines are not splitted. I guess it's not a server configuration thing. I run my python code on a CentOS7.

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the problem. With `exec_command` you aren't setting up a `pty` terminal, maybe that has something to do with it. You could try running `env` from `exec_command` and from a regular `ssh` session and see how the environment variables differ.

Comment: @tdelaney is correct. `exec_command` sends the `'exec'` message to the remote host. `invoke_shell` sends `'shell'` which indicates to the host a pty terminal is to be used. Perhaps you can try to echo the environment variables `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` -- Perhaps modifying them will address this with `exec_command`... There is a `get_pty` keyword for [exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) but I can't find any documentation for its use.

Comment: If all you want is a directory listing, you could do `ssh_client.open_sftp().listdir_attr('.')` and skip parsing `ls` output completely.

Comment: @tdelaney: TERM var is different. Executing `env` through `exec_command()` I get `TERM=vt100` on both Linux and AIX servers. Using a standard SSH client, I get `TERM=xterm-r6` on AIX and `TERM=xterm` on Linux. Using `invoke_shell()` and `channel.send()` I get the same `TERM=vt100` .   
@sytech: `$COLUMNS` is not set using `exec_command()` on both Linux and AIX. Using standard SSH client `COLUMNS=80` on Linux, and not set on AIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it: it was just a `pprint` strange behavior. I put the received lines in a list, and then `pprint` this list. If I do :

```
for line in received:
    print(line)
```

Then It's ok.
pprint printed :

```
['-rw-r-----    1 myuser   mygroup      23228063744 06 mai 11:41 '
 'my_file.txt-rw-r-----    1 '
...
```

I don't know why. Well, I'll stop using pprint.

Comment: you just need to add width parameter to pprint call